# allowSyntheticDefaultImports transpile configuration typescript babel?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, babeljs

In my [tsconfig.json](https://github.com/Falieson/react15-meteor1.5/blob/3a7c15d13d1d1e543d0165c80864c3449509e524/tsconfig.json)
I would like to use the compilerOptions.allowSyntheticDefaultImports=true option. My understanding is that it allows `import React from 'react'` , but when I try this I get an error *like* "React.createElement is undefined"

From what I've read setting this just tells TypeScript to ignore erroring when it should, but how do you fix the React.createElement error?

Besides typescript I'm using meteor which uses babel

Answer (score 1):

> TypeScript to ignore erroring when it should, but how do you fix the React.createElement error

You can pass your code through `babel` that will add the synthetic import for you.

## More

I would recommend against this option altogether and just use `* as`.

Comment: specifically: `import * as React from 'react';`

Comment: I initially accepted your answer but I have declined this answer because I state in the question that the system is using babel. I think a complete answer to this question will explain the babel fix. The knowledge in your answer already exists